# Moq System.IO.FileNotFoundException

Tags: c#, exception, xamarin, moq

I have exception for this code:

```
var _mobileClient = new Mock<IMobileServiceClient>();
_model = new MyGroupsViewModel(_mobileClient.Object); // Exception
```

system.io.filenotfoundexception could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies

[image: Stack Trace]

How i can fix it?

Comment: What file cannot be found?

Comment: this is all an exception, he has no the file name.

Comment: Assert.IsNotNull((new Mock<IMobileServiceClient>()).Object); gets similar exception

Comment: Are you using an assembly of Moq that you built yourself, by any chance?

Comment: I use NuGet `<package id="Moq" version="4.2.1507.0118" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Moq.AutoMock" version="0.3.2.1" targetFramework="net45" />`

Comment: Did you add all the nuget packages associated with WindowsAzure.Mobile? Looks like you might be missing a reference or so